# Create forget password functionality using AWS EC2

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently thinking of the process on how to create a "Forget Password" functionality for my app. I have not use AWS EC2 service before so I want to know how can I go about doing it or is there a sample tutorial for me to look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Um.. EC2 is just a compute service - ie: an alternative to running on your own hardware. It should have little to no impact on your code. Also unclear to what objective-c has to do with your question.

Comment: I'm looking for sample code to guide me in implementing "Forget Password" for my app. And since it's an iOS app, hence the objective-c tag. 

I know EC2 is like a server. What i'm asking is that to implement the above function, do I need EC2 since I need to send an email to the user or is there any other way? Basically, I have no idea how to implement the above function.

Sorry for not being clear about my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I am not wrong,you want to implement "Forget Password" functionality in the application installed in your AWS instance in which you need to send email using AWS service...

To implement the above requirement, you need to use Amazon SES service(you can also use other emailing service, but specifically if you want to use Amazon service for emailing then go for Amazon SES ) combined with Amazon EC2

In SES you should verify the email address from which you need to send emails, after verification you will get the required credentials using which you can send emails as intended.